# Is this Java Jar file compiled incorrectly?

Tags: java, android-studio, jar

I recently added another "jar" file to my AndroidStudio project, rt.jar.  It's the second module I've brought in, so I brought it in the exact same way as the first.

However when I try to debug I get this wonderfully long error in AndroidStudio below.  I get the sense that I might need to recompile the jar file mysef?  But am not sure.  I thought someone here might tell me exactly what I need to do so I don't waste a while lot of time.

p.s. I thought of perhaps doing through the source files for each class I need in my app, it's just a few.  But somehow I fear that might be too kludgy.

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.ConfigRepository$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.ConfigRepository$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.JSch$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.Util$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.


trouble processing "java/applet/Applet.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
```

Comment: What part of 'the recommended solution is to recompile the class from source' don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP, I guess I might be too new to know how to compile a jar file.  I did try getting the source at Oracle, but that link was dead.

Comment: `rt.jar` is the runtime. Why would you need to import the runtime when you're running in a Java runtime?

Comment: @ifly6, as I said am new.  I was following the exact steps I used when I brought in the FTP routines from JCraft.  Every Google I do points to rt.jar.  I've tried to find a different one, am trying to use "javax.sound.sampled" classes.  If you know which jar I need to bring in would appreciate it.

Comment: `import javax.sound.sampled;`

Comment: @ifly6, I couldn't do that at first so that's what sent me looking for libraries to add to the project.  Am now on the 2nd jar that I've included in my project for this, "tritonous-share-0.3.7.2"

Yet it causes me to have the same error at build time.

Is this all because I am choosing the wrong type of library?  And if so where can I get the right one?

Comment: I really hope this thread isn't dead.  I've hit a serious wall here.